# VBA Difference between FieldInfo and .NumberFormat = "@"

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a program extracting me data under .XLS format it gives me something like that :

[image: Extract of my file before the macro]

Then, I run a macro :

```
Dim file As String
Const r_as400 = "C:\test\"
Const r_colos = "C:\test\save\"
Const file_name= "TCODES_PRODUITS.xls"

Sub test()
'
' test Macro
'

'
    file= r_as400 & file_name

    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=file, Origin:=xlMSDOS, StartRow:=1, _
        DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
        Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 2), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 2), Array(5, 1), _
        Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), _
        Array(12, 1), Array(13, 1), Array(14, 1), Array(15, 1), Array(16, 1), Array(17, 1), _
        Array(18, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

After that my file is looking like this  :

[image: After Macro]

As you can see, in the first screen there is rows with only 1 digit and others with 13

After the macro, some row are equal to [image: 00000000000001]  others to [image: 0000000000000000000001]

I'd tried something, from the initial file I changed column D format into text (NumberFormat ('@')) but it doesn't change anything.

Someone can explain to me difference and how the VBA instruction know how much "0" must be present before "1" ?

Comment: Being a 'xls' file, why don't you try opening it directly? If simple open it using `Workbooks.Open(r_as400 & file_name)`, how the column in discussion looks?

Comment: @FaneDuru The macro has been done this way, I presume that if I open directly things should be the same as Screen 1;  I'm just trying to understand how the VBA instruction know how much "0" must be present before "1" because I need to know that in order to develop something else based on the final file rendered by the macro.

Comment: If you imagine that VBA (instruction) place there a specific number of "0", something else than "program extracting data" formatted there, you are on a wrong way. I would suggest you to open the xls in the normal way and process the resulted column in order to have 14 digits (13 "0" in case of 1). If you really need everything with 14 digits, I can place a piece of code doing that.

Comment: @FaneDuru I've got the answer to my Question, the fact is that my file is extracted in CSV format renamed ".XLS", if I open it in CSV I see all "real" digits. I don't know why but Excel remove "useless" 0 automatically

Comment: I told you why: It is guessing what format to use and does what I have just explained...

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next code. Of course, your used constants must exist as they are:

```
Sub testCreateNecessaryLeadingZeros()
  Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, lastR As Long, rng As Range, arr, i As Long
  
  Set wb = Workbooks.Open(r_as400 & file_name)
   Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
   lastR = ws.Range("D" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row on D:D
   Set rng = ws.Range("D2:D" & lastR)
   arr = rng.value 'place it in an array
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        arr(i, 1) = Format(arr(i, 1), "00000000000000")
   Next
   rng.NumberFormat = "@"  'format the range as text
   rng.value = arr         'drop the array content, at once
End Sub
```

Comment: I will check this ASAP thank you for helping buddy !